# Is it possible finding RSA key with only CRT exponents and a prime factor?

Tags: number-theory, cryptography

I am learning more RSA and I am facing with this problem.

I have given **dp** and calculated **dq** that:

$d \equiv dp (mod (p-1))$ 
$d \equiv dq (mod (q-1))$

Therefore, now I have a public exponent $e$, a ciphertext $c$ and a prime factor $q$, and two $dp$ and $dq$, all generated from textbook RSA.

As far as I researched, I only can decrypt if I know one more prime factor $p$. However, I haven't found any methods to reverse this from these numbers.

Are there any method to do this? Thank you.

Comment: I found a way to solve this. Thanks to this paper: https://eprint.iacr.org/2004/147.pdf, it says: "e*dp-1=t(p-1) for some 0 < t < e", at page 7. And it's just simple we search for every number t in range 0 < t < e and found potential p and check if it's a prime or not. This is the prime factor we need.

Comment: Write an answer your question with details?